What sort of information should be included in an academic's Letter of Recommendation (for species distribution mapping jobs in Germany)?
I graduated at the start of Coronavirus in the UK and have worked in entry-level jobs in healthcare (eg "coronavirus support worker") for much of the time since then. I am now sending speculative applications for paid internships in [faunistische] "Kartierung" in Germany at various environmental planning bureaus.
One of the larger bureaus requires documents in addition to the CV/Cover letter to be submitted as part of a speculative application, and I received advice that including my degree transcript and a letter of recommendation could strengthen my application.
I asked a member of staff who taught on a lot of my courses whether she would write me a letter of recommendation, and she has said that she is happy to. However, she would would like to know whether I have any more detail on what needs to be included in the letter.
I did an unpaid internship in writing for an online educational resource with her in 2017. I don't know whether she would actually need her memory jogged as to what I had been writing about for the internship, or about any feedback she had been giving me for coursework at the time. I also don't know if I should summarize what an environmental planning bureau does for her, or provide her a link to the website of one of these bureaus. I just don't know enough about what I need to specify.

For a recommendation letter it seems much more important who it is for instead of who is writing it. How is this related to academia?

This might be on topic at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/, but not here. Few users here have much knowledge of "species distribution mapping jobs".

Well I thought this question might relate to Academia as quite a lot of the staff at the environmental planning bureaus I have come across have PhDs (I assume a Biologist with a PhD would have input in reviewing my application). However I am obviously not an academic and I am not sure that the environmental planning bureaus count as academia. workplace.stackexchange doesn't actually have any Q&As to do with species distribution mapping jobs either - would migrating to gis.stackexchange.com instead be ok?

@Buffy after reading your comment, would I be right in thinking that I need to use my knowledge of "species distribution mapping jobs" (which few people on here have) to pick out relevant achievements or activities from my degree program (which might require me to spend time reviewing what I did in each module), and send a list of these to my former supervisor? Sorry for this basic question, my social skills are a bit iffy and I have been wondering if my former supervisor might be meaning "detail" which would be more straightforward/less time consuming to provide.

Are these positions that you want to apply to at some kind of research institute, presumably associated to a university or are they private businesses? In the first case, this could be considered on topic here, in the second you should move this to the workplace stackexchange.

@quarague I’m ok with the question being migrated to workplace.stackexchange if necessary (although I have a feeling the advice from there will be not quite as good as on here or on gis.stackexchange). First I will put forward info about some of the bureaus I'm applying to:
ifuplan.de/de/
Institute providing services to eg the Bavarian Academy for Nature Conservation and Landscape Management (ANL). Publication: https://www.ifuplan.de/images/ifuplan/projekte/oekosystemleistungen/OneEcosystem_2017_Germanys_Ecosystem_Services.pdf

fauna.de/profil.html
freelance faunistic expert who is a guest lecturer on courses at the ANL and is the Deputy Chairwoman of the Bavarian State Association for Amphibian and Reptile Conservation. She says she is a state-recognized specialist in reptile/amphibian protection in Bavaria.
Publication: fauna.de/texte/DGHT-Tagungsband24_Amphibienschutz-an-der-B305.pdf
bau-vogeler.de
Bureau which can supervise/publish PhD theses.
